# No Error, but jPanel2 is not showing while jPanel1 is ok

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I already try to find the solution online, no one can bring me to the solution. I create a program that have 2 jPanel, I intend to show jPanel1 when the program starts or click jLabel1. Then when I click jLabel2, jPanel1 hide, and jPanel2 show up. But only ipv4Menus that can show up (even I click ipv4but, it does show up). When I click ipv6but, no panel show up.

This is the analogy of my program which the problem occured :

```
//create jPanel1 (ipv4Menus) & 2 (ipv6Menus) variables;
//create jLabel1 (ipv4but) & 2 (ipv6but) variables; 

//this is groupLayout which showing

javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 255, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                            .addComponent(ipv4Menus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(ipv4Menus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
```

this is mouselistener of ipv4but:

```
ipv4But.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            remove(ipv6Menus);
            add(ipv4Menus);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
            ipv4ButMouseClicked(evt);
        }});
```

this is mouselistener of ipv6but:

```
 ipv6But.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            remove(ipv4Menus);
            add(ipv6Menus);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
            ipv6ButMouseClicked(evt);
        }});
```

Sorry for bad english or bad format, I am newly here. Any kind of response I would be happy & thanks.

Comment: *"Then when I click jLabel2, jPanel1 hide, and jPanel2 show up."* Make the label a button. Use a `CardLayout` to flip between the panels.

Comment: Thank you so much @AndrewThompson